# onActivityResult method not being called Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to send data from child activity to parent. But somehow, onActivityResult(..) is not getting called. here is code

Parent activity

```
selectedText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {



    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Parents.this,Child.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data.hasExtra("selText")) {
                        selectedText.setText(data.getExtras().getString(
                                "selText"));

                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Child Activity: I can see selected value set in the setResult(). But after finish of child activity, it's not going back to parent activity.

```
textListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int myItemInt,
                    long arg3) {
                selectedFromList =(String) (textListView.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("selText", selectedFromList);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: didn't work this after trying Intent data = getIntent() in child activity

Comment: Try adding some `System.out.println()`'s into `onActivityResult()` to see what code is actually being executed. Once you narrow it down you should be able to figure out the problem. If not, edit your post and tell us which lines are being executed.

Comment: So when i touch event is being called on parent activity..it goes into onTouch() and when it executes startActivityForResult(intent, 1) line, it goes to onActivityResult() with request code is 1. After that it jumps to Child Activity and load it.  After selecting value from ChildActivity.OnItemClick()..it finish the child activity but never returns back to onActivityResult() of parent. Hope it is clear

Comment: So, to clarify, you tried putting a `println()` in *very top* of `onActivityResult()` and nothing happened? Because what I think is happening is that `onActivityResult()` is actually being called, but either the **`switch`** statement or one of the **`if`** statements are preventing your code from executing.

Comment: Yes onActivityResult() got called while ParentActivity is being executed. It goes to switch (requestCode) {
  case 1:  but never enters into if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {} block. because child is not yet called. As per my understanding, this method will get called when child activity set data.  But it never got called again from when i finish with ChildAcitivity.

Comment: I was having this issue due to a mistake. I was calling `finish()` right after calling `startActivityForResult()`, what was causing my caller `Activity` to not receive the result, because it had finished right after it started the other `Activity`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the mistake. I had below line in manifest.xml for child acitivity.

```
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

after removing this line. it's working like a charm!!!

Thank You all for your input and suggestions.

Comment: I had singletask. Changing it to singleTop fixed the problem.

Answer (score 94):

For anyone stuck with same problem, a symptom not to receive `onActivityResult`, following cases can cause this issue.

- check you are using `startActivityForResult()` correctly, do not use `startActivity()`.
- if you do something in overriden `onBackPressed` method, `super.onBackPressed();` has to be positioned at the last of the method, not at the first line. (my case to spend 5 hours)
- remove `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in manifest or equivalent argument to create a intent.
- remove `noHistory="true"` in manifest of the callee activity.
- check `setResult()` is missed.
- `finish()` is called to close the activity. use `finishActivity()` to close callee activity.
- use `requestCode` more than zero. negative value does not work.

Comment: My case is setting the called activity "android:launchMode="singleTask" ", and remove it is worked :)

Comment: Note that `super.onBackPressed()` is not mandatory. Its the default case where you go back to the last `Activity` on the back stack, but you can replace that behavior entirely.

Comment: What is the problem with negative values. I thought of assigning positive req codes to the activities I create, and negative req codes to the activities part of Android and other SDK's. Because of a negative request code it failed to call the callback. Has google provided a justification ?

Comment: Negative value does not work should have its own upvote. That mentioned anywhere in the android documentation, btw?

Comment: @somedev yes, it is mentioned in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Comment: @RajanPrasad yes, mentioned here in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Comment: Also if the activity is heavy it could be killed unless you have `android:launchMode="singleTop"`in calling activity

Comment: Oh, yes. I called `myActivity.onBackPressed()` after the `myActivity.startActivityForResult()` and this was the reason why `onActivityResult()` did not work.

Comment: In my case, I was using ActivityResultLauncher and onActivityResult was not being called because I had enabled setting "Don't keep activities" in device's Developer options. So it might be worth considering that as well.

Answer (score 2):

My case was a little bit complex and I realized that I used by error a static reference pointing to the first instance of the buttons listeners in a sub activity.

At the first turn it was working, but when the user was returning from the parent activity, `onActivityResult` was not called.

Replacing the static references was the fix

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your case, but when starting the child activity make sure you use `startActivityForResult(intent)`, instead of `startActivity();`

Comment: I am using                  Intent intent = new Intent(Parents.this,Child.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

Comment: only extra part parent activity has  below method  
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade, R.anim.fade_right);
  this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);
  super.onPause();
 }

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine on my side. I'm able to pass data from Child activity and receive it in onActivityResult. Perhaps selectedItemList is empty?

Comment: Humm...how come it's not working on my side? i can see selected value in selectedItemList variable.

Comment: Not sure, but try to call: `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` at the top of method.

Comment: i tried that also..still not working..i dont know what is causing issue.

Comment: My question is, After finish of ChildActivity. It supposed to call ParentActivity.onActivityResult(...) but it's not being called.

Answer (score 1):

And intent that used to launch new Avtivity can not be set with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, because as per [android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) :

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from
>   the activity being launched.

Answer (score 1):

Use *singleTop* instead of *singleInstace* as *launchMode* as it maintains the activity in the same task.

Answer (score 0):

**onPause was effecting onActivityResult.**

One of the corner case might be:
my case was different and silly: The problem was in onPause, `finish` called and end the activity. Removed that and works well.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish(); // this line causing the issue removed it. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my manifest for the calling activity from `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to `android:launchMode="singleTop"` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

Remove `OnActivityResult()` method in the Main Class, it works perfectly... 
**MainActivity->>>>Fragments**