# Android doesn't return to activity after taking photo

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to create an app where I can take a photo and view the thumbnail.

I've followed the tutorial from https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html 
but with no luck.

The problem is my app won't return to the activity the camera started from.
Instead it returns to my MainActivity and opens up the navigation drawer..

Here's my camera activity:

```
public class CameraTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_test);
        //Haal de toolbar op
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        //zet de toolbar als action bar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //zet de homebutton
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        Button photoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photoButton);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();

            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ImageView bitmap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap);
            bitmap.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/testers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="be.kdg.integratieproject.fragments.FragmentMain">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feedback_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/lightteal"
        android:text="Webview"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:paddingTop="19dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:textColor="@color/lightgray" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_transparant" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/photoButton"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/darkorange"
        android:layout_below="@id/feedback_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="foto nemen"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/photoButton"
        android:id="@+id/bitmap"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution..

The reason was that onActivityResult was not called.

Remove `noHistory="true"` of the activity in the android manifest.

Thumbnail now works perfectly!

Source: [onActivityResult method not being called Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689404/onactivityresult-method-not-being-called-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change function `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` like this

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```