# onActivityForResult doesn't get called

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

In this code, `onActivityForResult` is never called.

My Activity :

```
class PersonalInformationActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private val READ_REQUEST_CODE = 2

    lateinit var user: User
    lateinit var email: EditText
    lateinit var phoneNumber: EditText
    lateinit var username: EditText
    lateinit var profilePicture: ImageView
    lateinit var photoURI: Uri

 //someCode

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        when (v.id) {
            R.id.profilePicture -> {
                importPicture()
                if (photoURI != null) {
                    try {
                        val file = FileUtil.from(this, photoURI)
                        RequestAddUserProfilePicture.MakeRequestTask(this, this).execute(user.token, file, photoURI.path!!.substring(photoURI.path!!.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
                        Log.d("file", "File...:::: uti - " + file.path + " file -" + file + " : " + file.exists())

                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "need pic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun importPicture() {

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
        startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                photoURI = data.data
                Log.d("URI", "Uri:" + photoURI.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546302/7937498
and tried trick but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: call 
`getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);`

Comment: Does `PersonalInformationActivity` contain any Fragment?

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif I called this.startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE) but it doesn't works

Comment: @BachVu not at all, it's a very simple activity.

Comment: Check result code `resultCode == activity.RESULT_OK`. It should be `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK`

Comment: Did you try to set breakpoint in first line of `onActivityResult`?

Comment: It's already like that in my code @Piyush. By the way onActivityResult isn't called so it's not related.

Comment: Have you gone through _Log_?

Comment: Yes @Boken. I have set breakpoint before startActivityForResult and another one first line onActivityResult. it doesn't stop in onActivityResult. it doesn't not enter.

Comment: @Piyush I tried to put a Log.d yes but I didn't find any character from logcat about my Log.d so it confirms that it doesn't enter in onActivityForResult

Comment: Open your Activity class and check onActivityResult() and log request code

Comment: what do you mean ? @VasudevVyas

Comment: Open your activity class where your  fragment define. override OnActivityResult() method in your activity and test response over there. like Log.e("TEST", recuestCode +""); or  print any value.

Comment: Use different request code in fragment. That works for me

Comment: Are you selecting any image? Permission check is done?

Comment: Yes after selected a picture, activityOnResult is not called, permission is done

Comment: If you can upvote my question I will appreciate it @Athira

Comment: I tried to refactor my Kotlin code into Java code and now it's working... @Athira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a real way to solve but I refactor this from Kotlin to Java (exactly the same code) and it works as well...

Answer (score 1):

Use different REQUEST_CODES for activity and fragment. I tried your code and tried different request codes 101 and 102, i got the result.

Comment: Finally it doesn't work. It worked one time only. I also tried on 2 emulators it doesn't work. I tried with request codes 101, 102, 10003...

Comment: You tried 101 for activity request and 102 for fragment?

Comment: I just tried right now, 101 for my activity and 102 for my fragment. It doesn't work

Comment: I tried on another physical device (huawei) also doesn't work. On Which API did you try ?

Comment: Lollipop, micromax

Comment: Before doing anything you try to print something in log

Comment: I'm already printing something in the logcat just before calling startActivityForResult(). My SDK project is 23 minimum (Marshmallow) so it's working for you because it's old I think.