# Why is onActivityResult not getting called?

Tags: android, firebase, onactivityresult

I have already checked the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689404/onactivityresult-method-not-being-called-android), but my app doesn't have most of those settings, including the manifest one. The ones I could try changing, I did. Still no luck.

Below is my code, and this is part of one of my tabs in TabHost. I am able to choose an image from gallery, but any statement after that isn't getting executed. No sysout statements are printed.

All my variables, except for the Button, are static. Could that be a problem?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(messageActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    messageActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    101
            );
        }
        databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        imgStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        imgRef = databaseRef.child("images");
        user = MainActivity.sendUser();
        et = findViewById(R.id.msg);
        et.setText("");
        send = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        System.out.println("Entered onActivityResult");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                bmp=bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 , true);
                encode();
                System.out.println("Encoded");
                upload();
                System.out.println("Uploaded");
                /*Code continues...*/

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".messageActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".chatActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".usersActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".afterRegister" />
        <activity android:name=".activityTwo" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

What's surprising is that, this exact same code works for me in all apps. But most of them are just 2 actvities long. Over here I've included it within a TabHost's activity, but based on my internet search, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the necessary permissions in the Manifest file?

Comment: Can you access the gallery? Maybe the problem starts there...

Comment: I'm able to access the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

test this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

specially this :

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly even this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to pick:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

**For testing purpose:**

If you are on android 6 and higher go to the apps manager on the device and then go to permissions and check if they are enabled `read` and `write`.

**For reality:**

If you are on android 6 and higher you must add runtime permissions instead of doing it manual.

more details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: Yeah, I've included those lines in the manifest. I've included the manifest code. I'm also checking for those permissions within the code, as shown.

Comment: Also as I said if you are running android 6 and higher, go to device app manager and enable permissions in your app for testing purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sadly even that doesn't work. Just tried it.

Comment: Can you tell me if you are running a device android 6 or higher.

Comment: My emulator is running android 7.0

Comment: Okay look go to the app manager on the device and find your app, you know I mean the place where you clear cache and uninstall the app.

Comment: And click on permissions of the app, and make sure to enable permissions read and write.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Storage permission is enabled.

Comment: private static int PICK_IMAGE = 100;

    private static int random=0;
    private static Uri imageUri;
    private static Bitmap bmp;
    static int currentPos = 3;
    private static EditText et;
    Button send;
    static DatabaseReference databaseRef;
    static DatabaseReference imgRef;
    static StorageReference imgStorageRef;
    static String user="";
    FirebaseUser fUser;