# Cannot get onActivityResult() to be called, no matter what

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

Im making a simple note taking app in Android Studio, and im passing a Note object via Bundle to my 2nd Activity, and everything works. However, the changes made to that Note object is not reflected on the original object, as I assume when its parceled it creates a new reference (I'm still new to Android Studio, so I'm not certain).

```
    override fun onItemClick(note: Note) {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NoteViewActivity::class.java)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable("note", note)
        intent.putExtras(bundle)

//        val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(
//            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
//        ) { result: ActivityResult ->
//            Log.d("result", "result was reached by contract")
//            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
//                Log.d("result", "result was reached by contract")
//                val data: Intent? = result.data
//            }
//        }
//
//        startForResult.launch(intent)
        startActivityForResult(intent, SECOND_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.d("ACTIVResult", "ActivityResult was called")
    }
}
```

In my 2nd activity, I have written code as follows:

```
class NoteViewActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private var note: Note? = null

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                saveChangeAndFinish()
                return true
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    fun saveChangeAndFinish() {
        val resultIntent = Intent()
//        resultIntent.putExtra("updatedNote", note)
        resultIntent.putExtra("test", "test")
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent)
        Log.d("resultIntentV2", resultIntent.extras.toString())
        finish()
    }
}
```

I've tried both startActivityForResult() <- which is deprecated -> and the newer method of using register(...), as i've commented out above.
I'm beginning to wonder if its some weird setting in my manifest or something, I don't know..
I've been trying to fix this for over an hour and no luck.?

I've seemingly exhausted all possible solution routes except asking for help, I looked at StackOverflow, and old forum posts on the web.

Comment: You snipped some code out of the onCreate of your second activity. Can you show where you unpack the note from the intent and assign it to the `note` property? If you didn’t do that correctly, it would explain the behavior.

Comment: @Tenfour04 It is now edited with full context in the onCreate() function.

Comment: And for code you only for first activity should shouw how you start second activity and the onActivityResult(). For thye second activity only show how you grab that intent with the bundle. And the few code lines before finisch().

Comment: Your conclusion is ok that your original intent is not updated. But in onActivityResult there is an Intent parameter. You are not using it. And before the finish() you create an empty intent without a bundle in it. Create a new bundle and put it in the empty intent.

Comment: `Cannot get onActivityResult() to be called` Is that true? Is it not triggered? I think it is. Please write a better subject for your post.

Comment: @blackapps how can I be sure it is called? It's not logging anything with
*Log.d("ACTIVResult", "ActivityResult was called")* which is why im assuming its not being called. I tried adding a new bundle to the intent and its the same, no Log.d showing when i saveAndFinish() back to the main activity.

Comment: @blackapps I removed the unnecessary code now

Comment: I see no reason that onActivityResult would not be called. That code looks ok. I dont know why it fails. It should be pretty elementary all. Put a Toast in it then you see quicker what happens.

Comment: Yeah thats why i'm so confused and why i posted the Manifest and Gradle, since i can't seem to figure out a problem code-wise.. I figured maybe something in the build tags are causing issues since I saw an old post saying something about "singleInstance" Launchmode (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546302/22596629). I'm so confused, I'll try out the Toast though and see what gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
At top level of the class, as an instance variable, i had created a itemClickListener object that was overriding the function, and the activity was starting based off of that object's function and not the one in the code. Since the first was using startActivity(), it was not able to fire onActivityResult().

Goofy mistake on my part after coding for so long. To fix it, i now made the registerForActivityResult() object in onCreate(), and then created the clicklistener object after:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) { result: ActivityResult ->
            Log.d("result", "result was reached by contract")
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("result", "result was reached by contract")
                val data: Intent? = result.data
            }
        }

        val itemClickListener = object : OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(note: Note) {
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NoteViewActivity::class.java)
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putParcelable("note", note)
                intent.putExtras(bundle)

                startForResult.launch(intent)
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark next to this answer. This will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions, and may help other developers who have a similar problem.